# get ID3 tags with japanese characters - PHP

Tags: php, id3, cjk

So I came up with a problem, everytime I upload an mp3 file and get it's id3 tags like for example the title, artist, etc. and it's in japanese character format it will be stored into the database or processed by the php as a set of letters and special characters. the database is already set to receive japanese characters. But I don't know why everytime the id3 tags are processed the encoding will be like that. here is my code.

```
 public function getTagsInfo($sFilepath) {
    $aTV23 = array( // array of possible sys tags (for last version of ID3)
        'TIT2',
        'TALB',
        'TPE1',
        'TPE2',
        'TRCK',
        'TYER',
        'TLEN',
        'USLT',
        'TPOS',
        'TCON',
        'TENC',
        'TCOP',
        'TPUB',
        'TOPE',
        'WXXX',
        'COMM',
        'TCOM'
    );
    $aTV23t = array( // array of titles for sys tags
        'Title',
        'Album',
        'Author',
        'AlbumAuthor',
        'Track',
        'Year',
        'Lenght',
        'Lyric',
        'Desc',
        'Genre',
        'Encoded',
        'Copyright',
        'Publisher',
        'OriginalArtist',
        'URL',
        'Comments',
        'Composer'
    );
    $aTV22 = array( // array of possible sys tags (for old version of ID3)
        'TT2',
        'TAL',
        'TP1',
        'TRK',
        'TYE',
        'TLE',
        'ULT'
    );
    $aTV22t = array( // array of titles for sys tags
        'Title',
        'Album',
        'Author',
        'Track',
        'Year',
        'Lenght',
        'Lyric'
    );

   $aTV23 = mb_convert_encoding($aTV23, "UTF-8");
   $aTV23t = mb_convert_encoding($aTV23t, "UTF-8");
   $aTV22 = mb_convert_encoding($aTV22, "UTF-8");
   $aTV22t = mb_convert_encoding($aTV22t, "UTF-8");
    // read source file
    $iFSize = filesize($sFilepath);
    $vFD = fopen($sFilepath,'r');
    $sSrc = fread($vFD,$iFSize);
    fclose($vFD);
    // obtain base info
    if (substr($sSrc,0,3) == 'ID3') {
        $aInfo['FileName'] = $sFilepath;
        $aInfo['Version'] = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,3,1))).'.'.hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,4,1)));
    }
    // passing through possible tags of idv2 (v3 and v4)
    if ($aInfo['Version'] == '4.0' || $aInfo['Version'] == '3.0') {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($aTV23); $i++) {
            if (strpos($sSrc, $aTV23[$i].chr(0)) != FALSE) {
                $s = '';
                $iPos = strpos($sSrc, $aTV23[$i].chr(0));
                $iLen = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,($iPos + 5),3)));
                $data = substr($sSrc, $iPos, 10 + $iLen);
                for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a++) {
                    $char = substr($data, $a, 1);
                    if ($char >= ' ' && $char <= '~')
                        $s .= $char;
                }
                if (substr($s, 0, 4) == $aTV23[$i]) {
                    $iSL = 4;
                    if ($aTV23[$i] == 'USLT') {
                        $iSL = 7;
                    } elseif ($aTV23[$i] == 'TALB') {
                        $iSL = 5;
                    } elseif ($aTV23[$i] == 'TENC') {
                        $iSL = 6;
                    }
                    $aInfo[$aTV23t[$i]] = substr($s, $iSL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // passing through possible tags of idv2 (v2)
    if($aInfo['Version'] == '2.0') {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($aTV22); $i++) {
            if (strpos($sSrc, $aTV22[$i].chr(0)) != FALSE) {
                $s = '';
                $iPos = strpos($sSrc, $aTV22[$i].chr(0));
                $iLen = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($sSrc,($iPos + 3),3)));
                $data = substr($sSrc, $iPos, 6 + $iLen);
                for ($a = 0; $a < strlen($data); $a++) {
                    $char = substr($data, $a, 1);
                    if ($char >= ' ' && $char <= '~')
                        $s .= $char;
                }
                if (substr($s, 0, 3) == $aTV22[$i]) {
                    $iSL = 3;
                    if ($aTV22[$i] == 'ULT') {
                        $iSL = 6;
                    }
                    $aInfo[$aTV22t[$i]] = substr($s, $iSL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $aInfo;
}
```

Result :

```
あなたを武装解除する converted automatically to B0j0_00fkdY00
```

Comment: Show the raw bytes the tags are encoded as.

Comment: How @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ?

Comment: Is this solved now? Also does using `"UTF-16"` work better than `"UTF-8"`? If still not working, then provide us a testable mp3 link with Japanese text...